# Entity Framework Extension Mismatch Error with Oracle DB (EDMX model)

Tags: .net, oracle, edmx, entity-framework-extensions

I'm currently using Entity Framework Extensions (version 7.22.4) on .NET Framework 4.8, with Entity Framework (version 6.4.4). My database is Oracle and I'm using Devart (version 9.11). I am trying to replace all my SaveChanges() calls with BulkSaveChanges() in my code.

During this process, I've encountered an error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.dll
> Exception thrown: 'NUnit.Framework.AssertionException' in nunit.framework.dll
> An exception of type 'NUnit.Framework.AssertionException' occurred in nunit.framework.dll but was not handled in user code.
> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details: Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <01.01.0001 00:00:00> in DATE_OF_CHANGE Column. Expected type is Byte[].

The relevant entries in my EDMX model look like this:

```
 <Property Name="DATE_OF_CHANGE" Type="TIMESTAMP" Precision="6" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
```

I found [this resource](https://entityframework-extensions.net/edmx) suggesting that my EDMX model might not be supported.

I would like to verify:

Is this the root cause of my issue?
If it is, what alternatives or workarounds can I use?
If it isn't, what could be causing this error, and how can I rectify it?
Are there more steps required with the EDMX model than those mentioned on the EF Extensions website?

Comment: Your EDMX has been read correctly, so it’s not related that your model is not supported.

The issue looks more that the conversion from `DateTime` to `Byte[]` is not done correctly by our EF Extensions library. I suggest to directly contact us so we investigate it deeper why this is happening on this specific case as it’s not the kind of issue we can solve on Stack Overflow.